# Spring Cloud Actuator's binding endpoints with unexpected behaviour

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator

In Spring Cloud Actuator visualization control, bindings endpoint is not giving correct result.

Here is my binding config

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;

import com.oxymoney.cashflow.cu.streams.EmailStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.cu.streams.SmsStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.walletbs.streams.AepsStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.walletbs.streams.GenericRechargeStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.walletbs.streams.MoneyTransferStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.walletbs.streams.PaymentStream;
import com.oxymoney.cashflow.walletbs.streams.WalletTransactionStream;

@EnableBinding({SmsStream.class,MoneyTransferStream.class,PaymentStream.class,WalletTransactionStream.class,EmailStream.class,GenericRechargeStream.class,AepsStream.class})
public class StreamConfig {

}
```

It shows on last stream binding, ideally it show all.

curl -H "Content-Type: application/js"http://localhost:18382/actuator/bindings"

```
[{"name":"cashflow_aeps-response","group":null,"pausable":true,"state":"running","extendedInfo":{"bindingDestination":"KafkaConsumerDestination{consumerDestinationName='cashflow_aeps-response', partitions=1, dlqName='null'}","ExtendedConsumerProperties":{"concurrency":1,"instanceCount":1,"maxAttempts":1,"backOffInitialInterval":1000,"backOffMaxInterval":10000,"backOffMultiplier":2.0,"extension":{"ackEachRecord":false,"autoRebalanceEnabled":true,"autoCommitOffset":true,"autoCommitOnError":true,"startOffset":null,"resetOffsets":false,"enableDlq":false,"dlqName":null,"dlqProducerProperties":{"bufferSize":16384,"compressionType":"none","sync":false,"batchTimeout":0,"messageKeyExpression":null,"headerPatterns":null,"configuration":{},"admin":{"replicationFactor":null,"replicasAssignments":{},"configuration":{}}},"recoveryInterval":5000,"trustedPackages":null,"standardHeaders":"none","converterBeanName":null,"idleEventInterval":30000,"configuration":{},"admin":{"replicationFactor":null,"replicasAssignments":{},"configuration":{}}}}}}]
```

Comment: What is your question? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Which version are you using, are the other bindings correctly configured,...? Also try to create a small MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to help you out.

Comment: Question is spring actuator binding for spring cloud stream, I have clearly mentioned that binding endpoint of actuator not showing all bindings annotated with @EnableBinding, it is always showing last binding

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? It was reported as an issue and has been addressed in 2.2.0 - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1650